# Java and mysql high concurrency bottlenecks solutions

Tags: java, mysql

We are developing a vehicle tracking system in which several GPS devices keep sending their GPS locations to the server using Tcp connection. Tcp communicator decodes the GPS location and inserts that data into the database and before inserting we do some selects and updates but all I do it using prepared statements. Right now, one thread of TCP communicator serves one device request.Immediately after creating the thread we get one connection from the pool. After decoding the GPS data is where we perform the multiple select, update and insert for each data. As number of devices are increasing, the number of concurrent connections to our Mysql database are also increasing. We are now anticipating 30 to 50 thousand devices pumping data every minute.Currently below is how the snippet of the whole tcp communicator looks like. I know eventually we will facing both insert bottleneck into the database. What will the best solution to over come this scenario? Will Java also be able to handle this many concurrency ?

```
public class comm8888 {
    HikariDataSource connectionPool = null;
    private Socket receivedSocketConn1;
    ConnectionHandler(Socket receivedSocketConn1) {
      this.receivedSocketConn1=receivedSocketConn1;
    }
    Connection dbconn = null;
    public void run() { // etc
     DataOutputStream w = null;
     DataInputStream r = null;  
     String message="";
     receivedSocketConn1.setSoTimeout(60000);
       dbconn = connectionPool.getConnection();
     dbconn.setAutoCommit(false);
     try {
         w = new DataOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream(receivedSocketConn1.getOutputStream()));
         r = new DataInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(receivedSocketConn1.getInputStream()));
         while ((m=r.read()) != -1){
             //multiple prepared based sql select,update and insert here.
         }
     }
     finally{
        try {
            if ( dbconn != null ) {
              dbconn.close();
            }
        }
        catch(SQLException ex){
             ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        try{
           if ( w != null ){
                w.close();
                r.close();
                receivedSocketConn1.close();
            }
        }
        catch(IOException ex){
           ex.printStackTrace(System.out);
        }
      }
   }
}


    public static void main(String[] args) {
      new comm8888();
    }
    comm8888() {
      try {

          HikariConfig config = new HikariConfig();
                config.setJdbcUrl("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/testdata"); 
                config.setUsername("****"); 
                config.setPassword("****");      
                config.setMaximumPoolSize(20);      
          connectionPool = new HikariDataSource(config); // setup the connection pool           
       }
          catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace(System.out);
         }
          try 
          {
                   final ServerSocket serverSocketConn = new ServerSocket(8888);                
                   while (true){
                            try {
                                    Socket socketConn1 = serverSocketConn.accept();
                                    new Thread(new ConnectionHandler(socketConn1)).start();                     
                            }
                            catch(Exception e){
                                e.printStackTrace(System.out);
                            }
                        }
          } 
          catch (Exception e) {
             e.printStackTrace(System.out);

          }

    }
}
```

Comment: Delegate to a REST endpoint or publish to a message queue.  Either way, some other server cluster processes the request/message to interact with the db. Each request/message is small and should be fast so the db connection should only be borrowed for a few milliseconds. Add nodes to the cluster as traffic increases.

Comment: @AndrewS so you are saying after I do my select and update on db just for insert I push into a queue is it? But how about my select and update statement?  Even if I add the nodes can the db select concurrent select and update?

Comment: Without knowing the SQL it's almost impossible to know if there are issues.  Adding more nodes and clusters and message queues are not always the answer, decent SQL and indexes make a huge difference.

Comment: Side bar: does a long lived socket eat carrier data?  What is the relative cost of a 60 second socket versus HTTPS calls every few seconds?

Comment: @AndrewS for the nodes I am planning like each node to process only 5 thousand devices that is possible for me to do the problem now is the single database at the backend ?

Comment: @NigelRen in fact for my big table i remove auto increment and did a combination field to become primary. I have decent indexes done too but I am worried about concurrent insert handling at the db level

Comment: You need to come up with some sort of figures, how many records, how 'live' does the data need to be.  Then look at some performance figures of MySQL on the sort of hardware your intending to run on.  You should be able to find some guidance on performance once you can quantify your requirements.

Comment: @NigelRen I have the figure that I will be running into at least minimal 30 to 50 thousand inserts per minute. But before this insert I will be doing 30 to 50 thousand select and update. The reason for every device which connect I will check the its id and then update the latitude and longitude and some other fields in the master table. Then i do insert into the gpsdata table.

Comment: @nigelren I am planning to run the db on a 24 cpu and 48gb ram? I can put my queries but it will be overwhelm on this question. Should I post it you or do it via chat?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Moved from comment to here to explain a bit more.

```
dbconn = connectionPool.getConnection();
...
while (...) {
   // dbconn is held for up to 60 seconds which is not scalable
}
```

So you could just get a dbConn when there is actually something to do to avoid a long lived db connection

```
while (...) {
    // got some more data to process - now get a dbConn 
    dbconn = connectionPool.getConnection();
    // do inserts, etc.
    // commit and release the connection!
}
```

Another approach is to completely offload the interaction with the database by publishing to a queue or calling a REST service.

```
while (...) {
    // got some more data to process
    // publish the data to a JMS queue
    // or post the data to a REST endpoint
    // there is no database interaction here at all!
}
```

Then the message consumer or REST endpoint processes the data and inserts/updates the db.  Each one of those messages/requests is small so the db connection is borrowed from the pool for only a few milliseconds (at most).  The server cluster handling the JMS message/POST request can be scaled independently of the server which initially received the raw socket data.

Comment: ok I will do with your first approach bring the get the data only then call the dbconnection pooling. I will do the select,update and insert inside and release the connection. What I am worried is the concurrent insert in one second can mysql handle up to 50 thousand within a minute?

Comment: for the initial server also I am going set a as a cluser of server where each only handle an incoming of 5 thousand devices. So I am planning to do all select,update and insert in that server?

Comment: I don't know mySQL capability, and with that volume it might become an I/O bound problem.  Do you have DBA architects/infrastructure people available to consult?

Comment: what do you mean by i/o bound problem? Will a good db hardware help me like for instance 24 cpu and 48gb ram?

Comment: The incoming data to the socket + the outgoing data to the database (assuming db is on another server) will consume bandwidth.  That volume of traffic _might_ consume all of the available bandwidth so a socket waiting for data could time out before the data hits the buffer, or an insert times out from network latency.

Comment: yes my different is different server altogether and the socket server will around 10 individual servers.  When you said socket waiting for a data could time out meaning the device could not connect to the socket is it ? So I need to prepare for a bigger data bandwidth also ?

Comment: yes - the bandwidth is something to keep an eye on as traffic begins to increase.

Comment: any idea what range of bandwidth will be required in Mb right?

Comment: Sorry - I can't help there.  That's where you'll need infrastructure people to help.

Answer (score 2):

One problem is every device try to connect the db which is not scallable solution if the device number will increase.
One approach will be processing batch by batch asynchronously .Store all message in a queue till it reach a batch size then insert as batch.It will save network as you are not inserting record one by one.

If you required further scallable solution then can go nosql solution or master-master replication multi node topology to support large traffic and availability .

For select and update you can use merge query which need to be analyse on your use case.Merge query will update if it is present or insert if not present.

Comment: I agree and I know the problem it that every device will try to connect to db. I am thinking on the lines of queue but I still need to make the select and updates so there I will still need database connection too. Is it possible to run the select and updates for multiple connection and only differ the selects?

Comment: Please check merge query if any help for your usecase.

Comment: I am thinking of running the select and update concurrently and pushing the insert into the queue so that later I can run bulk insert once the queue is full. But my worry now is that the select and update will require me to run database connection? Will the pooling be helpful?

Comment: Worst case if all request is update not insert then queue will not help.Merge query will solve in single query no need to select and update

Comment: I check there is no support for merge query on mysql.

Comment: No in all my cases I will do select and update and only finally do the insert. So I was thinking doing the insert in bulk method using the queue but the issue now is the select and update I dont have any other option

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-on-duplicate.html

Comment: the problem my update and select is from different table and my insert is into different tables. So based on certain criteria in the select I do the updates to the table and finally I do insert depending either into one single table or another table if needed.